# Flex PersistenceManager isn't retrieving my object, even though I can see it in debugger

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6, flex-mobile

I've just changed an app from a ViewNavigatorApplication to a TabbedViewNavigatorApplication and my persistence manager appears to have stopped working properly.

Here's the offending code:

```
protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    // Populate fields using last activity from storage
    pm.load();

    // Make request, display list of actions
    var registration:Registration = pm.getProperty("registration") as Registration;

    var service:Phonotes = new Phonotes();
    var response:AsyncToken = service.ActionList("actionlist", registration.installationId);
    response.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(onActionListResponse, null));
}
```

The pm object is created outside of this scope.

For some reason I keep getting this error:
`Main Thread (Suspended: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.)`

But the Variables tab on the debugger shows that `this.pm.so.data.registration` is correctly populated.

Anyone any ideas what's going on?

I haven't been able to find any examples searching on Google for this one, nor on this site, so I'm obviously doing something wrong, but it was working before I changed the application type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget everything.

I placed a breakpoint on the `creationCompleteHandler` and ran it through the debugger again and *poof* it worked...

Good ol' flash builder.